# Solved: C# MySqlConnection LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE error "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"

Tags: c#, mysql

While using MySQLConnection in C# trying to do a LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE, how to resolve the error "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"

Full error is:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException HResult=0x80004005 Message=The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Answer (score 0):

In the connection string, include AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;
Server also need to be set up to allow local load data infile

```
string connectionStr = "Server=" + server + "; Database=" + database + ";Uid=" + user + ";Pwd="+ pw + ";Port=" + port + "; CharSet=utf8;ConnectionTimeout=6000;DefaultCommandTimeout=6000;";

connectionStr += "AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;"; // Added on separate line for clarity

            try
            {
                sourceConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStr);                       
                sourceConn.Open();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error opening db connection: " + ex.Message + "   trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
```

Here's a list of connection options: https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/